# Weblog comment error

Tags: sitecore, weblog

I am using Weblog for blog functionality. Now I am facing one problem. I have created one Entry with name like 'sitecore-mvc', now when I am going to submit a comments it is giving me error 'End of string expected at position 39' if I changed Entry name like 'sitecoremvc' it works fine. There is some problem when I use '-' in Entry name. Any how I want to use '-' in url. Please give me solution.

Comment: Post the stack trace, please

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the issues in GitHub for Weblog this is a known issue.

See this link for a solution:

https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/issues/52

You should be able to swap out the `DuplicateSubmissionGuard` pipeline processor to a custom implementation that escapes hyphen characters in the path.

Comment: I have checked this link but I want Weblog dll for sitecore 8

Comment: You should create your own pipeline processor to replace the current one so it shouldn't matter.